# Quick way to simplify $\frac{\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}}{\frac{x-y}{x+y}-\frac{x+y}{x-y}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's a quick way to simplify $\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\displaystyle\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}}{\displaystyle\frac{x-y}{x+y}-\frac{x+y}{x-y}}$?

I tried to find another way to simplify it, but the one that has only worked so far involves multiplying terms out and subtracting them. There has to be a quicker way. It simplifies to $\displaystyle\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$, I’d note right away that the denominator is

$$\frac{(x-y)^2-(x+y)^2}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{-4xy}{x^2-y^2}\;,$$

so we have

$$-\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{4xy(x^2+y^2)}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{4xy}=\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2-(x^2-y^2)^2}{4xy(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{4x^2y^2}{4xy(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\;.$$

Answer (score 4):

As $\dfrac{\dfrac ab}{\dfrac  cd}=\dfrac{ad}{bc},$

$\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\displaystyle\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}}{\displaystyle\frac{x-y}{x+y}-\frac{x+y}{x-y}}$

$=\displaystyle\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2-(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}\cdot\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x-y)^2-(x+y)^2}$

Now use $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$